# Problem with booting Ubuntu from an external HDD

Tags: boot, external-hdd

As usual, I apologize in advance if someone else asked this before althoguh I've checked the forum but couldn't find something (exactly) similar to solve this. I have 2 laptops, one with windows 7 installed in its internal drive and an external usb drive with ubuntu 14 installed in it, connected all the time to pick whichever os i'd like to boot up with via grub2.  (by the way grub2 shows up most of the time but still occasionally windows boots up directly, bypassing grub2)  The other laptop is just windows 8.1 in its internal drive. Problem is, when I try to connect this external drive with ubuntu to my second laptop with windows 8.1.  Its a sony vaio, the boot menu could only be opened if you switch on using the assist button. I did, then changed the primary harddrive to external usb harddrive with ubuntu but it just doesn't see it. Could someone please shed some light on this ultra-mega-hiper noob problem? I though installing grub2 into my second laptop but that seems not necessary given that it works from the external when connected to the other laptop.

Comment: FYI, you seem to have used a backtick instead of an apostrophe, causing your question to be highlighted all wrong.  Commands are quoted with backticks to make them show up like `this`.

Comment: Sorry...wasnt on purpose

Answer (score 0):

Windows also has a fast boot option that has to be turned off. [Here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)'s an instructional site on how to disable that. You can also [change the default operating system](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-default-operating-system-for-startup-multiboot) to see if that helps.

Comment: unfortunately Windows is not able to see anything other than itself in that setting(control panel-system properties-advanced-start up and recovery). Besides I moved the internal hardrive to the last option on boot menu and the external to the first. That should do something but no..it insist booting up windows. I turned off fast boot as well....still nothing